# express4 passport desirializeuser TypeError: hex is not a function

Tags: node.js, openshift, passport.js

I tried nodejs login tutorial using passport.

deserializeUser is working well when hosted by c9.io

But hosted by openshift it makes error

```
TypeError: hex is not a function
    at Function.from (native)
    at Function.from (native)
    at new ObjectID (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:52:32)
    at ObjectID (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:31:42)
    at /opt/app-root/src/app.js:120:17
    at pass (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:347:9)
    at Authenticator.deserializeUser (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:352:5)
    at SessionStrategy.authenticate (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:53:28)
    at attempt (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:348:16)
    at authenticate (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:349:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at initialize (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/initialize.js:53:5)
```

My deserializeUser code is like this

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    cookieParser = require("cookie-parser"),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    assert = require('assert'),
    fs = require("fs"),
    XLSX = require("xlsx"),
    session = require('express-session'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),
    multer = require("multer"),
    passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;   

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log("serialize:%s",user._id);
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  if (!db) {
    initDb(function(err){});
  }
  if (db){
    var col = db.collection("users");
    col.findOne(ObjectId(id), function(err, user) {
      console.log("deserialize:%s",user.username);
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
});
```

The line (/opt/app-root/src/app.js:120:17) is

```
col.findOne(ObjectId(id), function(err, user) {
```

I think the function ObjectId is not working on openshift environment

Is it a just a bug? why working on c9.io but not on openshift??

Comment: I have also same problem. Did you find a solution for that ?

Comment: Can you try replicate the issue on a newer node version? For us, it disappeared whenever we tried 5.12.0 or 6.6.0, whereas we got the same error on Node 5.7.1

Comment: So I had the same problem. I found that upgrading my Node did the trick. What version are you using?

Comment: It was a bug of mongodb. After i update mongodb it solved! node was latest version. thanks for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting today a similar error related with some mongodb-core update.

I fixed it by forcing mongodb-core to the previous version i had:

```
npm install --save mongodb-core@1.3.18
```